# How can I download an artifact from one organization to another organization in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-artifacts, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am writing one staging yaml file our pipeline. I am able to get all the artifacts from our organization but when I try to download the same from other org, it throws an error like this:

> ##[error]xxxx: The project with id 'vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/xx-xx-xx-xxx-xxxx' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.